# How to limit working range with long files in VIM

Tags: vim

Sometimes I find I need to edit long files that have a lot of redundancy.  When I navigate by searching, I inevitably end up in a section of the file that I don't want to be in because it had a matching search result. (Imagine a long xml file containing many records, each with the same set of tags).

My usual approach is to copy the portion I'm interested in to another file, edit it there, then meld it back into the original.

I was wondering if VIM had a way to temporarily define a working range, such that all searches and even scrolling is limited to that range, until the range is disabled.

Comment: You can also define a search range using the `\%>l` and  `\%<l` items. Their use has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264120/vim-search-only-between-specific-line-numbers)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Narrow Region Plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn). It opens a new window with the selected range, after performing changes and save it brings that content back to your file.

Answer (score -1):

A command like the following can defined to simplify searching within a range:

```
command! -nargs=* Rs let a=split(<q-args>) | silent! exe '/\%>'.a[0].'l\%<'.a[1].'l\('.a[2].'\)'
```

To search for the word `xml` between (excluding) lines 4 to 10:

```
:Rs 4 10 xml
```

This even admits regular expressions, for instance to look for `foo` or `bar` between lines 4 to 10:

```
:Rs 4 10 foo\|bar
```

This saves some typing when compared to an equivalent search command:

```
\%>4l\%<10l\(foo\|bar\)
```